# Making data fetching faster on VIEW

Tags: oracle-11g, view

I have created a rest service which fetches data from Oracle database and send it back to the application from which the rest service is called  .

Below is the query to fetch data from `VIEW` ,this query supports pagination:

```
SELECT  WORKFLOW_ID,COLLABRATION_KEY,WORKFLOWDATE,CURRENTSTEP,
STEPTIME,REQUESTOR FROM ( SELECT VIEWPAGE.*, rownum PAGEREQUEST 
FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM VIEW1 WHERE CDATE 
     BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-01-06 00:00:00.0', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF1') 
       AND TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-01-14 23:59:59.009', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF3') 
   ORDER BY CDATE DESC )VIEWPAGE 
   WHERE rownum < ((pageNum*pageSize) + 1 )) 
WHERE PAGEREQUEST >= (((pageNum-) *pageSize) + 1)
```

The above query works fine when the no of records is very few ,but this query takes more than a minutes if no of records is in thousands .

We have already indexed most of the columns but still it is very slow  .

Any tips to make it faster would be highly appreciated.

Thanks .

**UPDATE :**

Here is the VIEW query as requested .

```
create view VIEW1 as
select TAB4.workflow_id , TAB4.collabration_key ,TAB4.WORKFLOWDATE ,TAB4.CURRENT_STEP_NAME,TAB4.CURRENTSTEP ,TAB4.STEPTIME,TAB4.JOB_STATUS,workflow_request.REQUESTOR from
(select workflow_id,collabration_key,TAB3.START_TIME as WORKFLOWDATE,batch_step_execution.STEP_NAME AS CURRENT_STEP_NAME , batch_step_execution.EXIT_CODE AS CURRENTSTEP ,batch_step_execution.start_time as STEPTIME ,TAB3.EXIT_CODE as JOB_STATUS
from batch_step_execution
inner join
(select * from app_id_mapping
inner join
(select batch_job_execution.job_execution_id,batch_job_execution.job_instance_id ,batch_job_execution.START_TIME ,batch_job_execution.EXIT_CODE
from batch_job_execution where start_time in (select max(start_time) 
FROM batch_job_execution where job_instance_id in (select job_id from app_id_mapping) group by job_instance_id)) TAB2
on app_id_mapping.job_id =  TAB2.job_instance_id) TAB3
on batch_step_execution.job_execution_id = TAB3.job_execution_id
where batch_step_execution.start_time = (select max(start_time) 
from batch_step_execution where batch_step_execution.job_execution_id = TAB3.job_execution_id)) TAB4
inner join workflow_request 
on TAB4.WORKFLOW_ID=WORKFLOW_REQUEST.WORKFLOW_ID
```

**UDPATE :-**

Here is the execution plan .

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |                      |     1 |   202 |   480   (2)| 00:00:06 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                       |                      |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                |                      |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS               |                      |     1 |   202 |   390   (2)| 00:00:05 |
|*  4 |     HASH JOIN                 |                      |     1 |   158 |   389   (2)| 00:00:05 |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN                |                      |     1 |    97 |   380   (2)| 00:00:05 |
|*  6 |       HASH JOIN               |                      |  4329 |   232K|   231   (2)| 00:00:03 |
|   7 |        VIEW                   | VW_SQ_1              |  4329 |   109K|   150   (2)| 00:00:02 |
|   8 |         HASH GROUP BY         |                      |  4329 | 90909 |   150   (2)| 00:00:02 |
|   9 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL    | BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION | 17405 |   356K|   149   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|  10 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL      | BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION  |  4329 |   122K|    80   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  11 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL       | BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION | 17405 |   713K|   149   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|  12 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL        | APP_ID_MAPPING       |  2565 |   152K|     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 13 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | SYS_C00434473        |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  14 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| WORKFLOW_REQUEST     |     1 |    44 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 15 |   FILTER                      |                      |       |       |            |          |
|  16 |    HASH GROUP BY              |                      |    25 |   475 |    90   (3)| 00:00:02 |
|* 17 |     HASH JOIN                 |                      |  4208 | 79952 |    89   (2)| 00:00:02 |
|  18 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL        | APP_ID_MAPPING       |  2565 | 10260 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  19 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL        | BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION  |  4329 | 64935 |    80   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter( EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM APP_USER."BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION" 
              "BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION",APP_USER."APP_ID_MAPPING" "APP_ID_MAPPING" WHERE 
              "JOB_INSTANCE_ID"="JOB_ID" GROUP BY "JOB_INSTANCE_ID" HAVING MAX("START_TIME")=:B1))
   4 - access("APP_ID_MAPPING"."JOB_ID"="BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION"."JOB_INSTANCE_ID")
   5 - access("BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION"."START_TIME"="MAX(START_TIME)" AND 
              "BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION"."JOB_EXECUTION_ID"="BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION"."JOB_EXECUTION_ID")
   6 - access("ITEM_1"="BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION"."JOB_EXECUTION_ID")
  13 - access("APP_ID_MAPPING"."WORKFLOW_ID"="WORKFLOW_REQUEST"."WORKFLOW_ID")
  15 - filter(MAX("START_TIME")=:B1)
  17 - access("JOB_INSTANCE_ID"="JOB_ID")
```

**UPDATE :-** Is their something wrong with the pagination logic ? I believe VIEW performance is fine .

Comment: You should post the DDL for your view and underlying tables.

Comment: Please add the execution plan (_formatted_ text please, no screen shots)

Comment: [a_horse_with_no_name](http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name) This is not screen shots ,Can you please tell me what do you mean by execution plan?

Comment: @DevG Query plans. https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/dbms_xplan

Comment: [a_horse_with_no_name](http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name) updated with execution plan.

Comment: @DevG - You have to put an @ symbol in front of the handle (name) of the person you are specifically addressing as above :-) for them to be notified of your comment.

Answer (score -4):

You can use **MATERIALIZED VIEW** to get faster response then the simple view in oracle.

here is the syntax for the same. try this in your query.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW hr.employees AS SELECT * FROM hr.employees;
```

Comment: Hi Tejas  , We always need updated data , i think MATERIALIZED VIEW is not a good option ,what do you think ?

Comment: I think Materialized works perfec. atleast you can try it once to check the response.

Comment: This is very confusing. It should be CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW employee_mv AS SELECT * FROM hr.employees. Calling it the view the same name as its own schema won't work (probably - don't have Oracle to test). Even if it does, it would not be a sensible thing to do.

Comment: This is only example that i have to show you, you can try this query at your own end to check response of your data only.

Comment: Still doesn't get away from the fact that giving database objects the same names is a **bad** (bad...) idea **even** if the syntax will work. I don't have Oracle handy to test.

Comment: We always need updated data from VIEW . With Materialized view we need to always trigger it to get updated data .

Comment: Check [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/materialized-views) - especially the bit about REFRESH ON COMMIT - AFAICS this is an automatic trigger. Don't know a lot about this, but you could test and see if it works for you?

Comment: [@Vérace](http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/34007/v%c3%a9race) thanks ,let me try this and see if it works for me.